# ¿Cómo ocultar los botones según el resultado de datos filtrados?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Estoy creando el siguiente paginador con varios filtros, hasta el momento todo correcto en mostrar datos al filtrar:

```
$strs = "";
$limit = 10;
$pagination_page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

if (!empty($_GET['page'])) {
    $page = $_GET['page'] ? : '';
} else {
    $page = 1;
}

if (!empty($_GET['show_length'])) {
    $to_page = $_GET['show_length'] ? : '';
} else {
    $to_page = $limit;
}

if (!empty($_GET['search_box'])) {
    $search_box = "%{$_GET['search_box']}%" ? : '';
} else {
    $search_box = NULL;
}

if (!empty($_GET['dateIndex'])) {
    $dateIndex = $_GET['dateIndex'] ? : '';
} else {
    $dateIndex = NULL;
}
if (!empty($_GET['dateEnd'])) {
    $dateEnd = $_GET['dateEnd'] ? : '';
} else {
    $dateEnd = NULL;
}


$from_page = (($page-1) * $to_page);

//SELECT * FROM tblproduct  WHERE MATCH (field1, field2, field3) AGAINST ('textbox')
$stmtPROD = $con->prepare("SELECT pr.id_product,
                                pr.cover_product,
                                pr.title_product,
                                pr.require_color,
                                pr.require_size,
                                pr.in_stock,
                                pr.stock,
                                pr.price,
                                pr.url,
                                pr.active,
                                ap.size_product,
                                ap.color_product
                        FROM tbl_products pr
                        LEFT JOIN tbl_additional_product ap ON pr.id_product = ap.id_product
                        WHERE ((? IS NULL) OR pr.title_product LIKE ?)
                        AND ((? IS NULL OR ? IS NULL) OR pr.date_product BETWEEN ? AND ?)
                        AND pr.id_enterprise = ?
                        ORDER BY pr.id_product DESC LIMIT ?, ?");
$stmtPROD->bind_param("ssssssiii", $search_box, $search_box, $dateIndex, $dateEnd, $dateIndex, $dateEnd, $entg_id_enterprise, $from_page, $to_page);

$stmtPROD->execute();
$stmtPROD->store_result();
$records = $stmtPROD->num_rows; //num_rows; num_rows();
if ($stmtPROD->num_rows > 0):

    ob_start();

    $stmtPROD->bind_result(
        $id_product,
        $prod_cover_product,
        $prod_title_product,
        $prod_require_color,
        $prod_require_size,
        $prod_in_stock,
        $prod_stock,
        $prod_price,
        $prod_url,
        $prod_active,
        $size_product,
        $color_product
    );
    while ($stmtPROD->fetch()) :
        echo $id_product;
        echo "<br>";
        echo $prod_title_product;
        echo "<br>";
        echo $size_product;

    endwhile;
    //$stmtPROD->close();

    $stmtPROP = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_products WHERE id_enterprise = ?");
    $stmtPROP->bind_param("i",$entg_id_enterprise);
    $stmtPROP->execute();
    $stmtPROP->store_result();
    $total_data = $stmtPROP->num_rows;
    $stmtPROP->close();
    $con->close();

    $total_page = ceil($total_data / $to_page);
    $prev = $page - 1;
    $next = $page + 1;

    if ($prev > 0) :
        echo "<li><a href='" . $pagination_page . "?page=1'><i class='icon-angle-double-arrow'></i></a></li>";
        echo "<li><a href='" . $pagination_page . "?page=$prev'><i class='icon-angle-left'></i></a></li>";
    endif;

    for ($i=1; $i<=$total_page; $i++) :
        if ($page==$i) :
            echo "<li><a class='page-link active' >". $page . "</a></li>";
        else :
            echo "<li><a class='page-link' href='" . $pagination_page . "?page=$i'>$i</a></li>";
        endif;
    endfor;

    if ($page < $total_page ) :
        echo "<li><a class='page-link' href='index2.php?page=$next'><i class='icon-angle-right'></i></a></li>";
        echo "<li><a class='page-link' href='index2.php?page=$total_page'><i class='icon-angle-double-right'></i></a></li>";
    endif;

    echo '</ul></div>';

    // Get the output into a variable
    $results_table = ob_get_clean();
else :
    $results_table = "<div>No se han encontrado resultados.</div>";
    $stmtPROD->close();
endif;
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])) :
    // If is an ajax request, output just the result table and exit
    echo $results_table;
    die;
endif;

echo $results_table;
```

Al momento en la tabla productos solo tengo 24 registros y como el límite de mostrar datos por default es 10, por lo tanto, me genera tres botones: `[1]` `[2]` `[3]`, hasta allí también todo va bien.

Cuándo cambio la condición de mostrar de 10 a 25 productos los botones de la paginacion desaparece, solo me deja un botón: `[1]` y es correcto, ya que sería ilógico mostrar más botones de paginación cuando se está mostrando todos los resultados.

De la misma manera me gustaría que funcione cuando busco un producto o más bien con todos los filtros, como se puede observar en la siguiente imágen:

[image]

Solo tengo un producto que cumple con la condición buscada `nike` por lo tanto, me mostrará un registro hasta aquí bien, ahora el problema es que me muestra los tres botones, debería solo mostrarme uno ya que es innecesario mostrar tres botones cuando solo existe un resultado, debería haber encontrado 30 registros con la condición de búsqueda para que se muestren los tres botones.

Al tener más de mil productos y al coincidir solo con uno los botones también deberían desaparecer:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Existe alguna manera de que los botones no se muestren así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sino algo así como he visto en otros sistemas o como Google página la numeración en sus búsquedas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: *Cuándo cambio la condición de mostrar de 10 a 25 productos los botones de la paginacion desaparece, solo me deja un botón: [1] y es correcto, ya que sería ilógico mostrar más botones de paginación cuando se está mostrando todos los resultados.* No es correcto realmente, si pones que muestre `25` y el total es `24` no debería mostrar siquiera el `1`... Sea como sea, creo que las cuestiones estéticas sería mejor resolverlas en el cliente, mediante reglas `.css`. Hay otro asunto que queda en el aire en la pregunta: ¿te dejas bajo la manga algunos registros, o vas a buscarlos siempre al servidor?

Comment: @A.Cedano Si realmente también pensé lo mismo en eliminar todos los botones cuando estén listados los 25 registros, estoy de acuerdo. Este buscador o filtros de datos no esta disponible para usuarios de todo el mundo es simplemente para la parte administrativa que puede buscar información rápida y precisa, pero algo estoy haciendo mal al generar los botones correctamente y concuerdo en eliminar el botín *1* si están listados todos los productos.

Comment: Yo creo que en el cliente tú puedes manejar dos datos: el total de registros y la cantidad que el usuario tenga definida para mostrar y a partir de ahí desarrollar tu lógica, desde el cliente, ocultando lo que haya que ocultar o mostrando lo que haya que mostrar. Es sólo una idea, que tampoco nunca he hecho paginación ni cosas así. Quizá otro dato que puede ayudar es que el servidor te mande una bandera para saber si ese grupo de registros pertenece al principio o al final, para ayudarte a decidir si debes seguir abriendo más números de página o no.

Comment: @A.Cedano Se ve muy interesante lo que comenta pero ya estoy atareado con un problema lógico, me gustaría que sea mejorable pero no tendría idea de como volver a empezar :/ Aunque el total de registros ya salen y la cantidad también digo creo que eso cumple ya que ya esta definido una salida de datos mínimo que sería 10 registros.

Comment: Solo una consulta para descartar: ¿Debes hacerlo en PHP o te podría servir un plugin como datatables.net que utiliza paginador de forma automática?

Comment: @EduardoMunizaga Hola amigo, en `PHP` lo deseo

Answer (score 0):

La paginación necesita de 2 consultas, que son casi idénticas en su lógica. La primera es la que te trae tus datos y tiene un limit, es decir esta:

```
$stmtPROD = $con->prepare("SELECT pr.id_product,
                                pr.cover_product,
                                pr.title_product,
                                pr.require_color,
                                pr.require_size,
                                pr.in_stock,
                                pr.stock,
                                pr.price,
                                pr.url,
                                pr.active,
                                ap.size_product,
                                ap.color_product
                        FROM tbl_products pr
                        LEFT JOIN tbl_additional_product ap ON pr.id_product = ap.id_product
                        WHERE ((? IS NULL) OR pr.title_product LIKE ?)
                        AND ((? IS NULL OR ? IS NULL) OR pr.date_product BETWEEN ? AND ?)
                        AND pr.id_enterprise = ?
                        ORDER BY pr.id_product DESC LIMIT ?, ?");
```

Luego necesitas otra función que te traiga la cantidad total de items (es decir sin colocar el limit), y es aquí donde está tu problema. Tú tienes:

```
$stmtPROP = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_products WHERE id_enterprise = ?");
```

Existe un join, pero al ser left join no es relevante. Lo que sí es importante son los filtros. Te falta:

```
WHERE ((? IS NULL) OR pr.title_product LIKE ?)
AND ((? IS NULL OR ? IS NULL) OR pr.date_product
```

Por este motivo te trae TODO, no solo lo del producto en cuestión.

Además para que sea eficiente lo mejor es hacer un count(*), entonces la segunda consulta queda

```
$stmtPROD = $con->prepare("SELECT count(*)
                        FROM tbl_products pr
                        WHERE ((? IS NULL) OR pr.title_product LIKE ?)
                        AND ((? IS NULL OR ? IS NULL) OR pr.date_product BETWEEN ? AND ?)
                        AND pr.id_enterprise = ?");
```

Ahora procedo a colocar tu código completo, pero te aclaro que no tengo donde probarlo, así que posiblemente tenga errores. Tu debes tomarlo solo a modo de ejemplo. Además incluyo la solución a tu segunda pregunta, de cómo limitar la cantidad de páginas a mostrar.

```
$strs = "";
$limit = 10;
$MAX_PAGES=8; // CANTIDAD MÁXIMA DE PÁGINAS A MOSTRAR

$pagination_page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

if (!empty($_GET['page'])) {
    $page = $_GET['page'] ? : '';
} else {
    $page = 1;
}

if (!empty($_GET['show_length'])) {
    $to_page = $_GET['show_length'] ? : '';
} else {
    $to_page = $limit;
}

if (!empty($_GET['search_box'])) {
    $search_box = "%{$_GET['search_box']}%" ? : '';
} else {
    $search_box = NULL;
}

if (!empty($_GET['dateIndex'])) {
    $dateIndex = $_GET['dateIndex'] ? : '';
} else {
    $dateIndex = NULL;
}
if (!empty($_GET['dateEnd'])) {
    $dateEnd = $_GET['dateEnd'] ? : '';
} else {
    $dateEnd = NULL;
}


$from_page = (($page-1) * $to_page);

//SELECT * FROM tblproduct  WHERE MATCH (field1, field2, field3) AGAINST ('textbox')
$stmtPROD = $con->prepare("SELECT pr.id_product,
                                pr.cover_product,
                                pr.title_product,
                                pr.require_color,
                                pr.require_size,
                                pr.in_stock,
                                pr.stock,
                                pr.price,
                                pr.url,
                                pr.active,
                                ap.size_product,
                                ap.color_product
                        FROM tbl_products pr
                        LEFT JOIN tbl_additional_product ap ON pr.id_product = ap.id_product
                        WHERE ((? IS NULL) OR pr.title_product LIKE ?)
                        AND ((? IS NULL OR ? IS NULL) OR pr.date_product BETWEEN ? AND ?)
                        AND pr.id_enterprise = ?
                        ORDER BY pr.id_product DESC LIMIT ?, ?");
$stmtPROD->bind_param("ssssssiii", $search_box, $search_box, $dateIndex, $dateEnd, $dateIndex, $dateEnd, $entg_id_enterprise, $from_page, $to_page);

$stmtPROD->execute();
$stmtPROD->store_result();
$records = $stmtPROD->num_rows; //num_rows; num_rows();

if ($records > 0)
{
    ob_start();

    $stmtPROD->bind_result(
        $id_product,
        $prod_cover_product,
        $prod_title_product,
        $prod_require_color,
        $prod_require_size,
        $prod_in_stock,
        $prod_stock,
        $prod_price,
        $prod_url,
        $prod_active,
        $size_product,
        $color_product
    );
    while ($stmtPROD->fetch()) :
        echo $id_product;
        echo "<br>";
        echo $prod_title_product;
        echo "<br>";
        echo $size_product;

    endwhile;

     $stmtPROD = $con->prepare("SELECT count(*) as total
                                FROM tbl_products pr
                                WHERE ((? IS NULL) OR pr.title_product LIKE ?)
                                AND ((? IS NULL OR ? IS NULL) OR pr.date_product
                                BETWEEN ? AND ?)
                                AND pr.id_enterprise = ?");
    $stmtPROD->bind_param("ssssssi", $search_box, $search_box, $dateIndex,
    $dateEnd, $dateIndex, $dateEnd, $entg_id_enterprise);

    $stmtPROP->execute();
    $stmtPROP->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($totalRows);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmtPROP->close();
    $con->close();


    $total_page = 1;

    if( $totalRows > $to_page )
    {
   
        $total_page = ceil($totalRows/ $to_page);

        $prev = $page - 1;
        $next = $page + 1;


        if ($prev > 0) :
            echo "<li><a href='" . $pagination_page . "?page=1'><i class='icon-angle-double-arrow'></i></a></li>";
            echo "<li><a href='" . $pagination_page . "?page=$prev'><i class='icon-angle-left'></i></a></li>";
        endif;

        //con esto mostramos cierta cantidad de páginas a la izquierda de la seccionada
        //y también a la derecha de la seleccionada, es decir la seleccionada queda relativamente al centro
        $left=ceil($MAX_PAGES/2);
        $desde= $page - $left + 1 ;
        $hasta= $page + $MAX_PAGES - $left;


        if($desde<=0 && $hasta >$total_page){
            $desde= 1;
            $hasta = $total_page;
        }
        else if($desde<=0 ){
            $desde= 1;
            $hasta= $MAX_PAGES;
        }
        else if($hasta > $total_page){
            $desde= $total_page - $MAX_PAGES;
            $hasta= $total_page;
            if($desde<=0){
                $desde= 1;
            }
        }

        for ($i=$desde; $i<=$hasta; $i++) :
            if ($page==$i) :
                echo "<li><a class='page-link active' >". $page . "</a></li>";
            else :
                echo "<li><a class='page-link' href='" . $pagination_page . "?page=$i'>$i</a></li>";
            endif;
        endfor;

        if ($page < $total_page ) :
            echo "<li><a class='page-link' href='index2.php?page=$next'><i class='icon-angle-right'></i></a></li>";
            echo "<li><a class='page-link' href='index2.php?page=$total_page'><i class='icon-angle-double-right'></i></a></li>";
        endif;

        echo '</ul></div>';

        // Get the output into a variable
        $results_table = ob_get_clean();

    }
}
else {
    $results_table = "<div>No se han encontrado resultados.</div>";
    $stmtPROD->close();
}

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])) :
    // If is an ajax request, output just the result table and exit
    echo $results_table;
    die;
endif;

echo $results_table;
```

***Update: Prueba funcionamiento paginación***

Eliminé las consultas sql para poder recrear la paginación, ingresando números fijos en las variables que necesitaban datos desde el mysql

```
$strs = "";
$limit = 10;
$to_page = $limit;
$MAX_PAGES=8; // CANTIDAD MÁXIMA DE PÁGINAS A MOSTRAR
$totalRows=800;
$page = $_GET['page'] ? : 0;

$total_page = ceil($totalRows/ $to_page);

$prev = $page - 1;
$next = $page + 1;


if ($prev > 0) :
    echo "<li><a href='" . $pagination_page . "?page=1'><i class='icon-angle-double-arrow'></i></a></li>";
    echo "<li><a href='" . $pagination_page . "?page=$prev'><i class='icon-angle-left'></i></a></li>";
endif;

//con esto mostramos cierta cantidad de páginas a la izquierda de la seccionada
//y también a la derecha de la seleccionada, es decir la seleccionada queda relativamente al centro
$left=ceil($MAX_PAGES/2);
$desde= $page - $left + 1 ;
$hasta= $page + $MAX_PAGES - $left;


if($desde<=0 && $hasta >$total_page){
$desde= 1;
$hasta = $total_page;
}
else if($desde<=0 ){
$desde= 1;
$hasta= $MAX_PAGES;
}
else if($hasta > $total_page){
$desde= $total_page - $MAX_PAGES;
$hasta= $total_page;
if($desde<=0){
    $desde= 1;
}
}

for ($i=$desde; $i<=$hasta; $i++) :
    if ($page==$i) :
        echo "<li><a class='page-link active' >". $page . "</a></li>";
    else :
        echo "<li><a class='page-link' href='?page=$i'>$i</a></li>";
    endif;
endfor;

if ($page < $total_page ) :
    echo "<li><a class='page-link' href='index2.php?page=$next'><i class='icon-angle-right'></i></a></li>";
    echo "<li><a class='page-link' href='index2.php?page=$total_page'><i class='icon-angle-double-right'></i></a></li>";
endif;

echo '</ul></div>';
```

Resultados:

1. Al inicio
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
2. Presionando 8

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3. Navegando a la página 80 (la última)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Obviamente todo está sin los CSS adecuados, pero la funcionalidad está

Comment: esto solucionaría solo el tema de la paginacion en búsqueda, cierto? Pero aún habría problemas con todos los botones que se generan dejando una mala imagen en el diseño, debería estar todo en horizontal y ocultarse cierta parte de la paginacion en lo que se vaya navegando tal cómo se muestra en la imagen de la paginacion de fondo azul de mi pregunta.

Comment: @J.Mick Están ambas soluciones en el código.

Comment: Solo se soluciono el tema de los botones amigo, pero al buscar un producto que solo existe un registro sigue saliendo los 8 botones por default que se han agregado y lo otro no es posible ir moviendo los números de la paginación así: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iin7p.jpg sin que este fijo `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8`

Comment: @J.Mick Me parece que hay un error en este if if ($records  > 0) creo que debería ser if ($records  > $to_page). Con respecto a los números, yo lo hice como lo tiene google, que no muestra los 3 puntos "...", pero si seleccionas la página 8 te debería aparecer 4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11 (solo si hay 11 o más páginas), es decir el número se va corriendo. Ahora si esto no pasa, favor avísame, porque como te decía antes no tengo como probarlo

Comment: @J.Mick Ya vi el problema de la paginación, mi error es que me quedó una variable dando vueltas (de una idea anterior) $actual_page debería ser $page. Ya edité el código para que lo pruebes

Comment: no corre los números amigo, queda siempre estático `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8` así vaya al final de la paginacion se muestra siempre eso.

Comment: @J.Mick Algo estaremos haciendo mal, porque traté de recrear la situación y como puedes ver en la actualización de mi respuesta, la paginación me corre

Comment: lo revisó tarde amigo, una pregunta con estás modificaciones se desaparecen también los botones al encontrar un solo registro o si por ejemplo tengo solo 7 registros desaparece el botón 1 que sabe quedar.

Comment: @J.Mick No debería mostrar la primera página, este if se encarga de eso if( $totalRows > $to_page )

Comment: amigo el tema de los botones ya funcionan es decir el corrido, pero no se oculta los botones cuando se busca algo https://i.imgur.com/2zeBBWl.png y esto creo porque se esta definiendo en `$MAX_PAGES=8; ` 8 botones en sí que se muestren fijo en la paginacion

Comment: cuando tengo tres registros en la base de datos al agregar esto `if( $totalRows > $to_page )` no me muestra nada en la paginación